# How to choose the right way to dispatch message in dbus

Tags: dbus

As far as I know there are three way to dispatch a message get from the dbus queue, dbus_connection_set_watch_functions/dbus_connection_dispatch/dbus_connection_register_object_path, I don't know the details about them, so I can't choose the right function to dispatch messages, I am so confused about these conceptions, is there some relations between them, or they are interdependent?

Any idea would be more than welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think maybe I have got the answer from the Source Codes of common_api, as the usecase of common_api shows, a DBusWatch will create from the libDbus codes when you get a new connection, then you can call to register DBusWatch callback with dbus_connection_set_watch_functions, and one of the arguments indicates addition callback, its type is DBusAddWatchFunction, it means the callback will be invoked once a new DBusWatch is added to the list, in addition to this, the callback will be invoke when dbus_connection_set_watch_functions execute, the arguments includes a DBusWatch, and a DBusWatch stands for a file descriptor, this DBusWatch represent the socket fd, so in this callback, you can use the fd operators to monitor the fd, such as poll. If someone write something to this socket you can read in the content, then you can parse it and pass them to dbus_connection_dispatch, dbus_connection_dispatch will operate the message in three steps:

First, any method replies are passed to DBusPendingCall or dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block() in order to complete the pending method call.

Second, any filters registered with dbus_connection_add_filter() are run. If any filter returns DBUS_HANDLER_RESULT_HANDLED then processing stops after that filter.

Third, if the message is a method call it is forwarded to any registered object path handlers added with dbus_connection_register_object_path() or dbus_connection_register_fallback().